# Standarization of values in sparse matrix RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I would like to use matrix factoring (by using ALS in MLlib to be exact) for product recommendations, where I don't have ratings, but use number of purchases (implicit information, sparse matrix). Before training I would like to standardize dataset by client (row in the matrix, where columns are products and intersection is an amount). Matrix has few millions rows and tens of thousands of columns, so I would like to use RDD as much as possible.

My data is stored in the list of tuples:

```
(int, int, int)

[(Client1, Product1, amount)
(Client1, Product2, amount)
(Client2, Product1, amount)
(Client2, Product3, amount)]
```

I would like standardize amount of products bought by client. I thought about groupByKey transformation, but don't know where to go from here.

**EDIT**: The main problem with the approach that I've taken was the usage of the RDDs and ALS implemented to work with RDDs (available in the mllib package) instead of main ML library that uses DataFrames (available in the ml package). Since nested transformation is not available in RDDs, usage of DataFrames greatly helped.

Comment: What sort of standardization would you like to apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *
>>> from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *
>>> 
>>> cm = CoordinateMatrix(rdd.map(lambda (c, p, a): MatrixEntry(c, p, a)))
>>> irm = cm.toIndexedRowMatrix()
>>> idxs = irm.rows.map(lambda row: row.index)
>>> vcs = irm.rows.map(lambda row: row.vector)
>>>
>>> nzr = Normalizer(1)
>>> rows = idxs.zip(nzr.transform(vcs)).map(lambda (index, vector): IndexedRow(index, vector))
>>> normalized = IndexedRowMatrix(rows).toCoordinateMatrix().entries.
```